# ASMX receive class as parameter

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I'm trying to receive a parameter of type class to a web method.
The class, which I build, is holding a list of inner classes.
The class looks like this

```
[Serializable]
public class InventoryCheckInput 
{

    public Item itemList { get; set; }

    [Serializable]
    public class Item
    {
        public string CatalogID { get; set; }
        public string Quantity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The web method looks like this

```
[WebMethod]
public InventoryCheckOutput OnlineInventoryCheck(InventoryCheckInput Items)
{
    return null;
}
```

is it possible to build a parameter as class like that?

Comment: Have you tried it?  That's usually the quickest way to see if it can be done.

Comment: Why are you using a legacy technology? Anyway, here is the list of supported types for XML Web Services. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3003scdt(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks for reply.  Of course i tried it and it didn't work. what kind of technology you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit classes and receive lists in client side..

```
     public class requestResponse 
{
    public bool status { get; set; }
    public string msg  { get; set; }

}
 public class district : requestResponse
{
    public int district_id { get; set; }
    public string district_name { get; set; }

}
 [WebMethod]
    public List<district> getDropDown()
    {
        List<district> list = new List<district>();
        Pro_DbCon db = new Pro_DbCon();
        SqlConnection con = db.dbconnectionEMIS();
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from DSS_District", con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                int idDistrict = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);
                string DistrictTitle = dr[1].ToString();

                district d = new district();
                d.status = true;
                d.msg = "";
                d.district_id = idDistrict;
                d.district_name = DistrictTitle;
                list.Add(d);
            }

            if (list.Count < 1)
            {
                district d = new district();
                d.status = true;
                d.district_id = 0;
                d.district_name = "No Data Found";
                d.msg = "";
                list.Add(d);
            }
            dr.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            con.Close();
            district s = new district();
            s.status = false;
            s.msg = ex.ToString();
            list.Add(s);

        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();

        }


        return list;

    }
```